# Why wont this update statement update all rows when it should?

Tags: mysql, sql

I was hoping the following query would update all rows where `updated=0`, but it doesn't. It does only a single update. Can you see why?

```
UPDATE scores t1
JOIN scores t2
ON FIND_IN_SET(t1.id, t2.vals)
SET t1.total = t1.total  + 1
WHERE t2.updated = 0;
```

**Table before running query**

```
"id"    "total" "vals"  "updated"
"1"     "0"     ""      "0"
"2"     "0"     ""      "0"
"3"     "0"     ""      "0"
"4"     "0"     "1,2,3" "0"
"5"     "0"     "1,2"   "0"
```

**Desired results**

```
"id"    "total" "vals"  "updated"
"1"     "2"     ""      "0"
"2"     "2"     ""      "0"
"3"     "1"     ""      "0"
"4"     "0"     "1,2,3" "0"
"5"     "0"     "1,2"   "0"
```

**What I'm getting**

```
"id"    "total" "vals"  "updated"
"1"     "1"     ""      "0"
"2"     "1"     ""      "0"
"3"     "1"     ""      "0"
"4"     "0"     "1,2,3" "0"
"5"     "0"     "1,2"   "0"
```

Since `update scores set totals = 1 where updated = 0` updates all rows, this should have worked too.

Comment: It only updates the rows that match the `ON` condition.

Comment: @Barmar I've updated my question with the results. It updates only once in my case, taking the row `4`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`UPDATE` just updates each row that matches the criteria, it doesn't perform the `SET` clause each time it matches a different row in the joining table. You can use this query to count the number of matches, and increment by that number.

```
UPDATE scores t1
JOIN (
    SELECT t1.id id, COUNT(*) matches
    FROM scores t1
    JOIN scores t2
    ON FIND_IN_SET(t1.id, t2.vals)
    WHERE t2.updated = 0
    GROUP BY id) t2
ON t1.id = t2.id
SET total = total + matches,
    updated = 1
```

[FIDDLE](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/aea14/1)

Comment: Works nicely. One small addition: If I need to set updated = 1 where the row belongs to the rows containing vals (in this case 4 and 5 so they wont be selected again when this query runs again), can it be done in the same statement, or it'll need to be done separately.

Comment: You can set as many columns as you want. I've updated the answer.

Comment: Actually, I meant set only the 4 and 5 in this case to 1. The rows which were selected for the update. I'll use this solution in a diff way. Thanks for helping.